# Batch class for mass deletion of Accounts

Tags: apex, batch

I've been trying to learn batch apex and for it I've written following code with the purpose of deleting accounts in mass. However, when I'm invoking it I don't see any of the accounts getting deleted. Can anyone point me out the mistake I'm doing?

PS: Updated code, but it's still now working(not deleting any account)

Batch class:

```
global class deleteAccounts implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

String query;

global deleteAccounts(String q){
    query=q;
}
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> scope){
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acc:scope){
        Account a = (Account)acc;
        accList.add(a);
    }
    delete accList;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
}
}


Code written in anonymous block to invoke batch:
deleteAccounts d = new deleteAccounts('select id from Account');
Database.executeBatch(d);
```

Comment: @Eric Sorry my bad , I've posted the updated code and there's no compilation error but still account deletion doesn't happen!

Comment: You may find an explanation by taking a look at the [Monitoring the Apex Job Queue](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_apex_job.htm) output.

Comment: Yep. Just now checked the apex job status and come to know that there were associated cased with some of the account so the problem!!

Answer (score 3):

You do not have a null constructor so you should be getting an error when running.

You also have not defined `query` so the class will not save

```
String query;
```

And your execute method should be

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<sObject> scope){
```

notice the List to match the interface you are using

This should execute it fine as you have to pass in the query:

```
deleteAccounts d = new deleteAccounts('Select ID From Account;);
Database.executeBatch(d);
```

You can also simplify the execute portion to:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> scope){
    delete scope;
}
```

Not sure how the class you posted in your question even compiled, in fact it produces

> Compile Error: Variable does not exist: query at line 4 column 5